# Cannot import Jimp into Angular 6 for image processing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, image-processing

I would like to use [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) with angular 6 to resize images from a base64 source before uploading them to the server. I tried to import it like this:

```
import * as Jimp from 'jimp';
```

which ended in a missing resource because only the browser code is loaded. Then I tried to load the jimp code itselft like this:

```
import {Jimp} from 'jimp/index';
```

which ended up in a lot of errors

```
Errors while compiling. Reload prevented.
    errors @ client?c480:161
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:883
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:881
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2957
wrapFn @ zone.js:1188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
client?c480:167 ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\myProject\node_modules\aws4'
errors @ client?c480:167
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:883
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:881
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2957
wrapFn @ zone.js:1188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
client?c480:167 ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\myProject\node_modules\ecc-jsbn'
errors @ client?c480:167
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:883
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:881
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2957
wrapFn @ zone.js:1188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
client?c480:167 ./node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\myProject\node_modules\oauth-sign'
...
```

I would also use an alternative library, but I only found jimp for pure JS image processing.

A solution was posted [in it issue list on github](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/325), but it did not work for me.

Comment: Did you get any luck with Angular + Jimp?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll not load it cause it'a lib for `NodeJS` so it's for 'back end' purpose .. you can't do it in front end in that way.

If you want to do in your Angular Front end .. i think you've to try to work on the `CANVAS`

maybe you can try something like this package:

```
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/re`size-base64
```

Comment: I know that is originally made for node, but it has a browser binding

Comment: angular 6 uses Webpack and Typescript. The project itself has examples for [native js and browser](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/browser/examples) implementations

Comment: so have you tried with a declare let require : any and then let Jimp = require(../lib/jimp.min.js); ?

Comment: require is not available in TypeScript as far as I know? I Thought need to import is as I wrote in the question?